# Openssl compilation error In file included from cryptlib.c:117: cryptlib.h:62:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, openssl

I tried to compile openssl library using this http://x2on.de/2010/12/16/tutorial-script-for-building-openssl-for-ios-iphoneipad/ but got

```
In file included from cryptlib.c:117:
cryptlib.h:62:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
cryptlib.h:63:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cryptlib.h:65,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../e_os.h:444:30: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
../e_os.h:449:29: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cryptlib.h:72,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../include/openssl/crypto.h:125:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cryptlib.h:72,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../include/openssl/crypto.h:175: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘size_t’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:465: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../include/openssl/crypto.h:465: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:466: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../include/openssl/crypto.h:467: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:468: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘void’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:470: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:471: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘void’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:477: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../include/openssl/crypto.h:477: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:478: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../include/openssl/crypto.h:479: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:480: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘void’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:482: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:483: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘void’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:500: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
../include/openssl/crypto.h:535: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from cryptlib.h:74,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../include/openssl/bio.h:634: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../include/openssl/bio.h:706: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../include/openssl/bio.h:707: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from ../include/openssl/err.h:127,
                 from cryptlib.h:75,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../include/openssl/lhash.h:186: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘FILE’
../include/openssl/lhash.h:187: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘FILE’
../include/openssl/lhash.h:188: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘FILE’
In file included from cryptlib.h:75,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../include/openssl/err.h:140:19: error: errno.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cryptlib.h:75,
                 from cryptlib.c:117:
../include/openssl/err.h:343: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
cryptlib.c: In function ‘CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric’:
cryptlib.c:430: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
cryptlib.c: In function ‘CRYPTO_THREADID_set_pointer’:
cryptlib.c:441: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
cryptlib.c: In function ‘CRYPTO_THREADID_current’:
cryptlib.c:507: error: ‘errno’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cryptlib.c:507: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
cryptlib.c:507: error: for each function it appears in.)
cryptlib.c: In function ‘CRYPTO_THREADID_cpy’:
cryptlib.c:518: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’
cryptlib.c: In function ‘OPENSSL_showfatal’:
cryptlib.c:906: error: ‘stderr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cryptlib.c: In function ‘OpenSSLDie’:
cryptlib.c:918: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
cryptlib.c: In function ‘OPENSSL_stderr’:
cryptlib.c:926: error: ‘stderr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
What can I fix it
```

Please if you know help me please how to fix this errors. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like standard header files are missing from SDKs or path is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to compile openssl library using this http://x2on.de/2010/12/16/tutorial-script-for-building-openssl-for-ios-iphoneipad/ but got

Your problems are due to path and sysroot problems. From the looks of it, that script is a horrible hack.

The OpenSSL project has a script it uses to set the environment and build the library for iOS devices. You can find it here: [setenv-ios,sh](http://wiki.openssl.org/images/a/ac/Setenv-ios-11.sh.tar.gz). Unfortunately, there is no documentation on the web or in its wiki. It is covered in the [OpenSSL FIPS User Guide 2.0](http://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf%E2%80%8E), though (see Appendix E).

Here's the recipe I use to build the library (that uses the script). Ensure the OpenSSL tar ball and script are located in the same directory (the 'root' directory below).

```
# Start fresh
$ rm -rf openssl-1.0.1e/
$ chmod a+x setenv-ios-11.sh

# From the 'root' directory
$ . ./setenv-ios-11.sh
$ tar xzf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.0.1e/

$ perl -pi -e 's/install: all install_docs install_sw/install:install_docs install_sw/g' Makefile.org
$ ./config shared -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/ios-6.1

$ make depend
$ make all
$ sudo -E make install
```

Be sure to include the leading ".' (dot) when setting the environment. After installation, your headers and libraries will be located in `/usr/local/ssl/ios-6.1`.

If you have any problems, consult the [OpenSSL FIPS User Guide 2.0](http://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf%E2%80%8E), but ignore the FIPS related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Depend what you need it for, you may consider use Cocoapods in you project, and then you could use  pod like this one: https://github.com/krzak/OpenSSL

just add to Podfile:

```
pod 'OpenSSL', :podspec => 'https://raw.github.com/krzak/OpenSSL/master/OpenSSL.podspec'
```

and go with coding.

Answer (score 0):

The error also might happen if you have both Windows SDK 10 and Windows Driver SDK 10 installed at the same time. It seem that the VCVARS will set wrong include path in such situation